# Could a Javascript redirect of our homepage result in an artificially high bounce rate?

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics, analytics

About a week ago we redirected our homepage to an Unbounce page in order to A/B test some design elements.  The test page contains all the same links to our old site, the only thing different is it's url and design.  Unbounce reports a bounce rate of about 50% but Google Analytics reports a 98%+ bounce rate. Our GA code is stock Universal Analytics, no funky filters, nada.

Comment: Once I started using some custom event tracking to track button presses on a page, the bounce rate went way down. Apparently any event recording will make the visit a non-bounce.  See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: Actually there is a flag that you can set that says if the event should affect the bounce rate or not.

Comment: Thanks to those who answered above --- What I really want to know is if in fact the JS Redirect would cause the bounce rate issue.  So far I can find no conclusive answer to this.